# HTML required tag not working for company and name

Tags: javascript, php, html, opencart

the required attribute don't seem to work for Company and Phone. It is just working for Name and Email. Can anybody help me with this?

```html
  <form>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required />
                
                <input type="text" name="company" value="" placeholder="Company" required />
                
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required />
                
                <input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone" required />
                <br />
                <div onclick="catalog_popup_submit();" 
                class="button">Continue</div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Normally, that should work. Maybe because of something in `catalog_popup_submit();`?

Comment: Are you sure the inputs don't contain (whitespace) characters?

Comment: Why don't you add submit button in form...?

Comment: @Swellar actually thats a pop up to show a thank you message when they signed up for the catalogue.

Comment: @GyandeepSharma it was actually a 2nd party did it. Then I try to alter it but its not working.

Comment: If it is just a pop-up, none of the `required` in the inputs should work. Try removing the `div` then replace it with an `<input>` or `<button>` with `type=submit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required />

            <input type="text" name="company" value="" placeholder="Company" required />

            <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required />

            <input type="text" name="phone" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" placeholder="Phone" title="Enter 10 digit mobile number"required />
            <input type="submit" value="continue" />  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
<div onclick="catalog_popup_submit();" 
            class="button">Continue</div>
```

Try to include a submit button in the form.

```html
<html>
<body>
<form>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required />

            <input type="text" name="company" value="" placeholder="Company" required />

            <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required />

            <input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone" required />
            <br />
   <input type="submit" value="continue" />        
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" required />

            <input type="text" name="company" value="" placeholder="Company" required />

            <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required />

            <input type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone" required />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="continue" />        
</form>
</body>
</html>
```